# Setting transform translate of <g> using Javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

What I set for transforming `<g>` is

```
const svg = d3.select('target-svg')
const g = d3.select('target-g')

svg.call(d3.zoom().on('zoom', () => {
    g.attr('transform', d3.event.transform)
})
```

Now, I am trying to set *transform* attribute of `<g>` svg tag using following sample javascript code.

```
g.attr('transform', 'translate(100, 100) scale(1)')
```

The issue is that **the `<g>` tag is transleted fine** but **when zoom in and out using mouse wheel, the `<g>` is translated to origin position**.

For example, if the origin coordinate of translate of `<g>` is (0, 0) and I translate it to (100, 100), the `<g>`'s (x, y) is located (100, 100). But when I zoom it, the `<g>` is go back to (0, 0).

How can I stop it?

Comment: Do you mind adding a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) (or any other demo) to show what is the problem? I get what it is, and why, but it's easier to have your demo / what you're working with

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A D3 zoom behavior does not track an element's transform attribute - afterall, a zoom behavior might not alter it (zooming on canvas, changing color or shape on zoom, granularity of data, applying a zoom to different elements rather than the one triggering events, etc).

When you apply a transform with `d3.event.transform` you are applying the current zoom transform, which starts with a translate of `[0,0]` and a scale of `1`. In other words, unless you specify otherwise, the default initial zoom event with a d3 zoom behavior will always be relative to this initial state. This is why the zoom is not relative to the manually set element's transform value.

To unify a manually set transform attribute and the zoom behavior's transform, use the zoom to manage both. You can manually set the transform attribute of the `g` with the zoom behavior:

```
var transform = d3.zoomIdentity.translate([100,100]).scale(1);
svg.call(zoom.transform, transform);
```

The first line manipulates a d3 zoom identity to create a new transform. The second line applies it, calling a zoom event in the process, which triggers a zoom.on event.

With this approach the zoom manages both the use of manual transform and event based transforms, so that the zoom is never out of date or "unaware" of what transform is currently applied to a selection.

Altogether, this might look like:

```js
var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width',500)
  .attr('height',400)
var g = svg.append('g');

var rect = g.append('rect')
  .attr('x', 750) 
  .attr('y', 100)
  .attr('height',50)
  .attr('width',50);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .on('zoom', function() {
  g.attr('transform',d3.event.transform);  
  })

var initialTransform = d3.zoomIdentity
  .translate(-700,-40)
  
svg.call(zoom);
svg.call(zoom.transform,initialTransform);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```